# django models dependancy between two classes

Tags: python, django, models

I have 2 models in my django app, where both the models contain multiple instances of the other class. Eg) Say a topic can contain many books, and a book may belong to many topics. So, both must have a manytomanyfield of the other. My code:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)

class Book(models.Model):
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic)
```

Now the problem is, i get an error as 'Book' is not defined. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Add quotes around the model name: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the name of the model as a string to `ManyToManyField` instead of the model itself, [see here](http://serk.io/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) (`ForeignKey` behaves the same way).

Code:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    books = models.ManyToManyField('Book')

class Book(models.Model):
    topics = models.ManyToManyField('Topic')
```

**Edit:**

I blindly answered this without noticing the same thing as Daniel. You only need to have this relationship defined in one of the models, not both ways.

Answer (score 1):

You do *not* want this. "a topic can contain many books, and a book may belong to many topics" is the description of a basic many-to-many field in any case. Define it on one side only.

Answer (score 0):

Use the name of the model in quotes, eg

```
app1/models.py
class Topic(models.Model):
    books = models.ManyToManyField('app2.Book')

app2/models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    topics = models.ManyToManyField('app1.Topic')
```

[As described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)